# Switching between classes

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to switch between two classes in XNA from my 'Game1' class, I've run into several errors along the way trying different ways to make it work but I'll post the nicest looking one with the error 'Win32 Exception was unhandled - The system cannot find the file specified'

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GameTime gameTime = new GameTime();
    Game a;
    aastring b;
    bool c = false;

    public Game1()
    {
        a = new Game();
        b = new aastring();

        if (c == false)
            a.DoAll(gameTime);
        else
            b.DoAll(gameTime);
    }
```

-

```
public void DoAll(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //LoadContent();
        Draw(gameTime);
        do
        {
            Update(gameTime);
        }
        while(outa == false);
    }
```

-

```
public void DoAll(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

I'm pretty sure there will be a lot more problems once I get this to work but I've been stuck on this for days.

Comment: On which line are you receiving this error?

Comment: It is on the line, Public Game1() and the line a = new Game(); has a grey box over it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your classes in constructor, but dont try to put all game logic here. Switch between classes in `Update` and `Draw` methods.